# example of an n-transitive but not infinitely transitive group action on a space

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, topological-groups, counterexamples, homogeneous-spaces

> **Definition.** An action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ is *strongly $n$-transitive* if $G$ acts transitively on $n$-tuples of distinct elements in $X$ (via the diagonal action), and is *$n$-transitive* if $G$ acts transitively on *unordered* subsets of size $n$ in $X$.

The automorphism group of a connected topological manifold of dimension at least two acts strongly $n$-transitively for all $n$. On the other hand, for actions of groups that are smaller, the situation is different:

> **Theorem.** (Kramer, following Tits) There is no locally compact, $\sigma$-compact topological transformation group $G$ which acts effectively and $4$-transitively on a Hausdorff non-totally-disconnected space $X$.

(As a side note, by stating the theorem like this, I am butchering a beautiful and intricate classification of all $2$-transitive group actions satisfying the other hypotheses)

My question is whether there is any room between these extremes by weakening Kramer's hypotheses:

> **Question.** Does there exist a group $G$ that acts (strongly?) $n$-transitively but not $(n+1)$-transitively on a space $X$ for $n>3$?

For finite discrete or indiscrete $X$, the symmetric and alternating groups are examples, along with some of the Mathieu groups, but let's exclude those. My preference would be for either $X$ or $G/G_x$ to be a connected manifold but I'll take what I can get.

This question was inspired in part by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/245312/kappa-homogeneous-topological-spaces).

*Linus Kramer*, MR 2009240 [**Two-transitive Lie groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/crll.2003.085), *J. Reine Angew. Math.* **563** (2003), 83--113.

Comment: According to Hull and Osin (https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.04182), this is an open problem.

Comment: @AndreasThom thank you! You're talking about Question 6.1, right? There they assume that the group is countable, and in fact only consider transitivity degree only for countable groups; do you have any idea why? I would be totally fine with something uncountable (say, a Lie group, although Kramer/Tits makes that seem unlikely).